# ant build using javac/gwt shows errors when eclipse/gwt build does not

Tags: gwt, compilation, javac

If the gwt project in Eclipse uses Eclipse to compile the java code using the automatic build feature then the gwtc compile using ant does not show any problems.  If however, I clean all the existing .class files and then execute an ant build which runs javac and then gwtc, I get problems with my JPA entities such as:

> [ERROR] Line 12: No source code is available for type javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute; did you forget to inherit a required module?

I should note that I am making sure that the classpath for the ant build is using the same exact set of libraries that is present in the Eclipse "Java Build Path".  Since Eclipse does not apparently provide a log of the build process I cannot determine if there is some divergence.  Since the projects have to build on Hudson on the build server (which has the problem I outlined) I cannot rely on a dev machine doing the .class generation and then gwtc doing the gwt compilations.

Answer (score 0):

If the JPA entities are in a separate project, you will need to include the .java files also in the separate project's jar files.

Otherwise, you will need to ensure that all the JPA entities are inside the client directory of the GWT module.

Comment: I should have specified that they are contained inside the project and are not a seperate project.  We have been using this technique for a while but suddenly this issue showed up.  I presume either Eclipse is using jars different than the ones I have in the WEB-INF/lib (even though they match the java build path) or it is some ordering issue.